# plot the sum of each element of tuples

Tags: python, matplotlib, count, sum

I have a corpus and I'm trying to visualize the volume of the labels (the second element of each tuple)

**corpus:**

```
[(['plot', ':', 'two', 'teen', 'couples', 'go', 'to', ...], 'neg'),
 (['the', 'happy', 'bastard', "'", 's', 'quick', 'movie', ...], 'neg'),
 (['it', 'is', 'movies', 'like', 'these', 'that', 'make', ...], 'neg'),
 (['"', 'quest', 'for', 'camelot', '"', 'is', 'warner', ...], 'pos'),
 (['synopsis', ':', 'a', 'mentally', 'unstable', 'man', ...], 'neg'),
 (['capsule', ':', 'in', '2176', 'on', 'the', 'planet', ...], 'pos'),
 (['so', 'ask', 'yourself', 'what', '"', '8mm', '"', '(', ...], 'neg'),
 (['that', "'", 's', 'exactly', 'how', 'long', 'the', ...], 'pos'),
 (['call', 'it', 'a', 'road', 'trip', 'for', 'the', ...], 'pos'),
 (['plot', ':', 'a', 'young', 'french', 'boy', 'sees', ...], 'neg')]
```

**I tried:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8, 6))
labels_vol = [label[1] for label in corpus] #to get the second element of each tuple

labels_vol.sum().plot.bar(ylim = 0)
plt.show()
```

**my output:**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-c3174c6618f3> in <module>
 10 
---> 11 labels_vol.sum().plot.bar(ylim = 0)
 12 plt.show()

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sum'

<Figure size 576x432 with 0 Axes>
```

Comment: You cannot sum up strings and expect to get an object out that would have a `plot` method. Start earlier... what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes, I was stupid, sorry. I have 1000 'neg' tags and 1000 'pos' tags and I would like to represent this information in a graph...

Comment: What kind of representation are you expecting? Do you simply want a count of `neg` and `pos` (i.e. a barplot with two bars), or do you want to know how many `neg` and `pos` each of a certain category received?

Comment: @pitanga _I have 100 ‘neg’ tags and 1000 ‘pos’ tags and **I would like to represent this information in a graph..._** That’s a whole other question, one which is too broad/vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually like to use numpy, which would look like

```
import numpy as np
# ...

plt.bar(*np.unique(labels_vol, return_counts=True))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The error already says it:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sum'
```

it must be

```
a = sum(list)
```

and then plot this, but note this will only work for numeric data types.

Comment: I took the liberty of noting that `sum` will only work on numeric data types, since the data in the question has a string for each second tuple element.